# Aggregate initialization of noncopyable base class

Tags: c++, c++17, aggregate-initialization, noncopyable

I am constructing derived class from non-copyable base class. I would like to aggregate-initialize `Base` in the initializer:

```
// for convenience, could be any other way to disable copy
#include<boost/noncopyable.hpp>
struct Base: public boost::noncopyable{
    int a;
};
struct Derived: public Base{
    Derived(int a): Base{a} {}
};
```

but I am getting:

```
error: could not convert ‘a’ from ‘int’ to ‘boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable’
```

As I understand, `noncopyable` cannot be initialized, fair enough. Can I then somehow craft the aggregate initializer so that noncopyable initialization is skipped? (I tried e.g. things like `Base{{},a}` without real understanding, but that did not work either: `~noncopyable` is protected).

Or will I need to explicitly define `Base::Base` which will skip the `noncopyable` initialization, using it from `Derived::Derived` instead of the aggregate initialization?

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate initialization of the base class you tried

```cpp
Derived(int a): Base{{}, a} {}
//                   ^^
```

Would have worked if the constructor of `boost::noncopyable` wasn't `protected` (see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wG8kyiybLlJxvnWY)).

The easiest fix should be to add a constructor to the base class.

```
#include <boost/core/noncopyable.hpp>

struct Base: private boost::noncopyable
{
    int a;
    Base(int a_) : a{a_} {}
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    Derived(int a): Base{a} {}
};
```